# Nothing is happened when I put comment button

Tags: python, django

Nothing is happened when I put comment button.I wanna make a page which is shown comment&recomment.I wrote codes in views.py

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
   model = POST
   template_name = 'detail.html'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['comment_form'] = CommentCreateForm()
    context['recomment_form'] = ReCommentCreateForm()
    return context 

class CommentCreateView(generic.View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentCreateForm(request.POST)
        post = POST.objects.get(pk=kwargs['post_pk'])
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.target = post
            obj.save()
        return redirect('detail', pk=post.pk)


class ReCommentCreateView(generic.View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ReCommentCreateForm(request.POST)
        comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=kwargs['comment_pk'])
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.target = comment
            obj.save()
        return redirect('detail', pk=comment.target.pk)
```

in urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('comment/<int:post_pk>/',views.CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment'),
    path('recomment/<int:comment_pk>/', views.ReCommentCreateView.as_view(), name='recomment'),
]
```

in detail.html

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DETAIL</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="comment-area">

    {% for comment in post.comment.all %}
    <div class="media m-3">
        <div class="media-body">
            <h5 class="mt-0">
                <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{% by_the_time comment.created_at %}</span>
                {{ comment.name }}
                <span class="lead text-muted">{{ comment.created_at }}</span>
                <a href="{% url 'recomment' comment.pk %}">Recomment</a>
            </h5>
            {{ comment.text | linebreaksbr }}

            {% for recomment in comment.recomment.all %}
            <div class="media m-3">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">

                        {{ recomment.name }}
                        <span class="lead text-muted">{{ recomment.created_at }}</span>
                    </h5>
                    {{ recomment.text | linebreaksbr }}
                </div>
            </div>

            {% endfor %}
            <form action="{% url 'recomment' comment_pk=comment.id %}" method="post">
                {{recomment_form}}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="re-comment">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <form action="{% url 'comment' post_pk=post.id %}" method="post">
        {{comment_form}}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="comment">
    </form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

in models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    target = models.ForeignKey(POST, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I put comment button, no error happens but same page which is form's content is blank is shown.I wanna show `{% for comment in post.comment.all %}` ~ `{% endfor %}`,so I really cannot understand why I cannot do it.I think values are not in model, so I print out `print(obj)` in CommentCreateView's class, and correctly value is shown in terminal.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the objects actually created in the DB? There's some info missing in the post (like the Form itself, etc), anyway:

If you didn't set the `related_name` argument on the foreign key, the correct access to post's comments is via `post.comment_set.all()`, see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

May I point out that you're doing a lot of work, that Django's generic views can do for you (guess it's OK if you're learning, otherwise, it's just more code to maintain).

Things like `CreateView`, `UpdateView`, and `DeleteView` from `django.views.generic.edit`. For more info see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms